# Calculate products count based on category tree table

Tags: postgresql, query, count, recursive, tree

It is necessary to calculate how many products were created in each category, of course, that the products created in a child must be considered for the parent.
How can i do that SQL/Postgresql?

Second explanation if first is not clear - I should create a query that will calculate products count based on a categoryId and categoryIds childs too.

Database schema

```
Table Category
-------------
id
name
parentId
-------------
ROWS
1 rootCategory null
2 child1 1
3 child2 2




Table Product
------------
id
name
categoryId
------------
ROWS
1 productOne 1
2 productTwo 2
3 productOne 2
4 productOne 3
```

If categoryId = 1 is selected it should display products count from this category ant its children. In this example answer for root category count should be 4, because it has also two subcategories that have also three items in product table.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in a [repro]. I've taken the putting up [your sample data here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1074132bc246cbcaa4e0c5d26eaa37a8). Please see also [ask] & welcome to the network :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cats AS (
   SELECT 1::bigint AS id
 UNION
   SELECT c.id
   FROM category AS c
      JOIN cats ON c.parentid = cats.id
)
SELECT count(*)
FROM product
   JOIN cats ON cats.id = product.categoryid;
```

This query uses category `id` number 1 as an example. Replace it with the appropriate category `id` or use a parameter instead.

Comment: My query counts everything under category 1 if you need a different one, replace "1" with the `id` you want.

Comment: You saved my ass buddy! THANK YOU!